# Adding Route Shapefile (PolylineM) to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, linear-referencing, route

I'm new to QGIS (and to this amazing forum as well) and I already have an issue :

I received a Route Layer in SHP format (PolylineM). I've easily loaded this file into QGIS but it doesn't seem to recognize the "M" aspect of it.

I couldn't find anything recent about it but I've read that in the past, QGIS couldn't deal with PolylineM. Is it still the case?

Problem is I have nothing to re-calibrate that Route if that's the only option.

Comment: Doesn't spatialite support XYZM?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, it's still the case that you cannot use the M-part of geometries. I know that PostGIS supports M and it depends on your use case if that can be an alternative.

Comment: that's what I thought. Too bad. So the workflow you're suggesting is : Import the shp into Postgis and load the newly postgis layer into QGIS? I will try it

Comment: Adding my network as a Postgis layer doesn't help unfortunately. It is not seen as a route though it's been imported as ArcM